# Compare two non-matching lists and identify the row with maximum matching elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Background**

I've two lists (of lists), each created by reading data from two address tables.

The first element in each row is the unique identifier of the list row and the remaining elements are used for address comparison.

Each list would look somewhat like this:

List 1 (cli add)

```
['3', 'V8T5G2', 'VICTORIA', 'BR', 'CANADA']
['543', '234', '654', 'BELMONT', 'AVENUE', 'V8S3T4', 'VICTORIA', 'BR', 'CANADA']    
['28', '70', 'RUSHTON', 'RD', 'M6C2X8', 'YK', 'ON', 'CANADA']
```

List 2 (struct add)

```
['7H0044', '234', '654', 'BELMONT', 'AVENUE', 'V8S3T4', 'VICTORIA', 'BC', 'CANADA']
['7H0033', 'V8T5G2', 'VICTORIA', 'BC', 'CANADA']
['7H0001', '700', 'RUSHTON', 'ROAD', 'M6C2X7', 'YORK', 'ON', 'CANADA']
['7H0034', '217', 'BONNYMUIR', 'DRIVE', 'V7S1L4', 'WEST', 'VANCOUVER', 'BC', 'CANADA']
```

**Task Goal**
My task is to compare the addresses from the test list to the other list, and flag all the matching and non matching records.

I am looping through each row in list 1 and comparing with each row of list 2, element wise. If all the elements pulled from list 1 row are found in any row from list 2, I mark that record as 'matching' and retain the row from list 2. Have been able to identify the completely matching records.

**Problem Point**
The real challenge is about the non matching rows. For the non matching records from list 1, I would want to identify the most closely matching row from list 2. e.g. if row from list 1 has matching elements in three rows from list 2, I would want to pick up the list 2 row which has the highest number of matching elements.

**Expected Outcome**
In the data shared above, from the list 1, second row (id 542) has complete match. But the other two records aren't yielding a complete match.

I want to be able to create a list of un-matching records and capture umatching elements:

```
[[comparison record from list 1],[Most matching record from list 2],[non-matching elements from list 1]]
```

So for above shared data, I need a new list (of lists) which looks something like:

```
[['3', 'V8T5G2', 'VICTORIA', 'BR', 'CANADA'],['7H0033', 'V8T5G2', 'VICTORIA', 'BC', 'CANADA'],['BR']]
[['28', '70', 'RUSHTON', 'RD', 'M6C2X8', 'YK', 'ON', 'CANADA'],['7H0001', '700', 'RUSHTON', 'ROAD', 'M6C2X7', 'YORK', 'ON', 'CANADA'],['70','RD','M6C2X8', 'YK']]
```

The code below gets me the results partially. I am not being able to find a way to filter the highest matching rows.

**Code Snippet**
Here is how I found the matching and non-matching records (list 1 is referred by cli_add_fnl and list 2 is struc_add_fnl). Have also figured the way to list the unmatched elements and count of matching elements. Just need a way to pull only the rows with max count for list element 1.

```
### Step 4 - Identifying the matching and non matching addresses ###  
validated_addresses_all = []
invalid_addresses_all = []

for cli_add in cli_add_fnl:            
    comparison_cli_add=cli_add.copy()

    #removing the id column from comparison
    comparison_cli_add.pop(0)


    for struct_add in struct_add_fnl:
        matching_elements = [address_element for address_element in comparison_cli_add if address_element in struct_add]

        #capture the matching records
        if matching_elements == comparison_cli_add:
            validated_addresses_all.append(cli_add)
        else:
            invalid_addresses_all.append(cli_add)
            invalid_addresses_all.append(struct_add)
            invalid_addresses_all.append(len(set(comparison_cli_add) & set(struct_add)))
            invalid_addresses_all.append(nonmatching_elements)

#remove the duplicate entries
fnl_validated_addresses = [] 
for add in validated_addresses_all: 
    if add not in fnl_validated_addresses: 
        fnl_validated_addresses.append(add)
```

Comment: You should look into using sets:
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

Comment: If any of the answers has helped you, please accept them as answers to help close the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it with ignoring position and the first item by comparing the values that are in `adds` and `struct_adds` and internally keeping a counter of the highest matches. As long there is a match it will update the counter and gets the index of the highest match else in the example below, it does nothing. Differences from item in `add` and the highest matches are then compared.

The results are then appended accordingly to a list.

```
adds = [['3', 'V8T5G2', 'VICTORIA', 'BR', 'CANADA'],
        ['543', '234', '654', 'BELMONT', 'AVENUE', 'V8S3T4', 'VICTORIA', 'BR', 'CANADA'],
        ['28', '70', 'RUSHTON', 'RD', 'M6C2X8', 'YK', 'ON', 'CANADA']]

struct_adds = [ ['7H0044', '234', '654', 'BELMONT', 'AVENUE', 'V8S3T4', 'VICTORIA', 'BC', 'CANADA'],
                ['7H0033', 'V8T5G2', 'VICTORIA', 'BC', 'CANADA'],
                ['7H0001', '700', 'RUSHTON', 'ROAD', 'M6C2X7', 'YORK', 'ON', 'CANADA'],
                ['7H0034', '217', 'BONNYMUIR', 'DRIVE', 'V7S1L4', 'WEST', 'VANCOUVER', 'BC', 'CANADA']]

results = []

for add in adds:
    match_count = 0
    match_index = 0
    for idx,struct_add in enumerate(struct_adds):
        matches = [add_item in struct_add[1:] for add_item in add[1:]]
        if matches.count(True) > match_count:
            match_count = matches.count(True)
            match_index = idx
    if match_count == 0:
        pass # no matches
    else:
        highest_match = struct_adds[match_index]
        differences = [i for i in add[1:] if i not in highest_match]
        results.append([add,highest_match,differences])
```

Or if you want to use `set` operations, which should be more effecient as suggested in the comments you can replace the `for` block with:

```
for add in adds:
    match_count = 0
    match_index = 0
    for idx,struct_add in enumerate(struct_adds):
        matches = set(add[1:]) & set(struct_add[1:])
        if len(matches) > match_count:
            match_count = len(matches)
            match_index = idx
    if match_count == 0:
        pass # no matches
    else:
        highest_match = struct_adds[match_index]
        differences = list(set(add[1:]) - set(highest_match[1:]))
        results.append([add,highest_match,differences])
```

Both yields the same results:

```
results
>>
[[['3', 'V8T5G2', 'VICTORIA', 'BR', 'CANADA'],
  ['7H0033', 'V8T5G2', 'VICTORIA', 'BC', 'CANADA'],
  ['BR']],
 [['543',
   '234',
   '654',
   'BELMONT',
   'AVENUE',
   'V8S3T4',
   'VICTORIA',
   'BR',
   'CANADA'],
  ['7H0044',
   '234',
   '654',
   'BELMONT',
   'AVENUE',
   'V8S3T4',
   'VICTORIA',
   'BC',
   'CANADA'],
  ['BR']],
 [['28', '70', 'RUSHTON', 'RD', 'M6C2X8', 'YK', 'ON', 'CANADA'],
  ['7H0001', '700', 'RUSHTON', 'ROAD', 'M6C2X7', 'YORK', 'ON', 'CANADA'],
  ['70', 'RD', 'M6C2X8', 'YK']]]
```

I should also add that in this example and also not to further complicate things, it will take the **first** highest match. This part is managed in the `if` clause comparing the count of true matches must be more than the current count of matches.